# What is the difference between iptables -X and iptables -F?

Tags: iptables

In many examples, I see the following 2 consecutive commands:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

From the man page, I cannot figure out the difference between flushing and deleting.  Is there a difference between these two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all chains you can -F :

```
+---------------+       +---------------+
|               |       |               |
| Chain MyChain |       | Chain MyChain |
|     Rule 1    |  -F   |      is       |
|     Rule 2    |       |     empty     |
|     Rule 3    |  ==>  |               |
|               |       |               |
+---------------+       +---------------+
```

For **user defined chains only** (chain created with iptables -N MyChain) you can -X if it is empty :

```
+---------------+
|               |
| Chain MyChain |         Chain MyChain
|      is       |  -X      does not exist
|     empty     |
|               |  ==>
|               |
+---------------+
```

Both

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

are used because one can delete a user defined chain only when it is empty. Built-in chains cannot be deleted, but can be flushed.

Answer (score 5):

`iptables -F` flushes the rules of a chain.

http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=iptables+-F

> -F, --flush [chain]
>          Flush the selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given).  This  is  equivalent  to
>          deleting all the rules one by one.

`iptables -X` deletes a chain.

http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=iptables+-X

> -X, --delete-chain [chain]
>          Delete  the  optional user-defined chain specified.  There must be no references to the chain.  If
>          there are, you must delete or replace the referring rules before the chain can  be  deleted.   The
>          chain  must  be  empty,  i.e.  not contain any rules.  If no argument is given, it will attempt to
>          delete every non-builtin chain in the table.

Comment: Yes, I read the man page. What I want to know is if there is a difference. Cause the end result seems to be exactly the same.

Comment: The difference is the same as deleting all files in a directory, or the directory itself.

Comment: A rule is not the same as a chain. Edit: ptman explained it better :)

Comment: Yes. iptables -X deletes user defined chains